# Fourier transform of exponential of minus Euclidean norm

Tags: fourier-transform

Where can I find the following Fourier transform:

$\mathcal{F}[\exp(-a\|x\|)](\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\exp(-2\pi i \langle\omega, x\rangle) \exp(-a\|x\|) dx$

where $\| x\|$ is the standard Euclidean norm, i.e. $\| x\|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots +x_n^2}$

Thanks!

Comment: See the last [formula there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Formulas_for_general_n-dimensional_functions)

Comment: You can find it here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220006/computing-the-fourier-transform-of-exponential-decay-in-mathbbr2/4220125#4220125