# What is the Fourier transform of exp(-abs(x))?

Tags: fourier-transform

I know the result of one dimensional case.

However, I can't find out what it is for the multidimensional case, i.e. the following integrals.
$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-a|x|} \,e^{-i \xi x}\,\mathrm d x
$$
I tried to use n-dimensional spherical coordinate, so I arrived to the following
$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\pi x^{n-1} \sin^{n-2}(\theta)\, e^{-ax-i|\xi|x\cos(\theta)} \,\mathrm d\Omega_{n-2}\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d x
$$

where $\mathrm d\Omega_{n-2}$ is solid angle for $S^{n-2}$

But, I cannot go further. I can't find out how to do integration. How can I do the integration?

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer right now, but check Theorem 3 of this paper: https://www.math.arizona.edu/~faris/methodsweb/hankel.pdf

Comment: Thank you a lot, I didn't know about Hankel transformation, so It's really interesting. But, still, I don't know well about the property of Bessel function, and I still have difficulty on deriving the result I want

Comment: The integral isn't trivial.

Answer (score 2):

As proved in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220006/computing-the-fourier-transform-of-exponential-decay-in-mathbbr2/4220125#4220125), the answer is with your conventions
$$
\boxed{\mathcal F(e^{-a\,|x|}) = \frac{2\,a \,(2\,\pi)^{n/2}}{\omega_{n+1}\,(a^2 + |x|^2)^{(n+1)/2}}}
$$
where $\omega_{d} = \frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)}$.