# Fourier transform of $x \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto (1+x^2)^{-\alpha}$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I hope that the answer is not somewhere in the forum. I searched without success.
I would like to compute the fourier transform of $f:x \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto (1+x^2)^{-\alpha}$ where $\alpha > 1/2$. Or, if there is no closed form, i would like to obtain approximation of $\mathcal{F}[f](k)$ when $k \to 0$.
I know how to deal with the case $\alpha = 1$ using complex integration and inverse fourier formula. But I struggle to generalize this method.
Do you have any hint or suggestion of approach?
Thanks,

Comment: Wolframalpha only [gives it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=fourier+transform+%281%2Bx%5E2%29%5E%28-e%29) in terms of [modified bessel function of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html), as $$\mathcal{F}[f](\omega)=\frac{2^{1-\alpha}|\omega|^{\alpha-\frac12}K_{\alpha-\frac12}(|\omega|)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$$ (for real $\omega$).

Comment: Thank you, very much. It is enough for me, since the asymptotic $|\omega| \to 0$ is well-known for this function. Do you have an idea of how to derive the identity given by wolframalpha?

Comment: Confirmed by [Basset's integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called Bessel potentials https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_potential.
You can already find several formulas and the asymptotic behavior on the Wikipedia page. You can find some other properties in Stein *Singular integrals and differentiability properties of functions* (1970), Chapter V, Section 3. In particular, a formula I like to get properties of these functions, is the following integral representation
$$
B_s(x) = \frac{\omega_s}{2} \int_0^\infty t^{\frac{d-s}{2}-1}\, e^{-\pi/t}\, e^{-\pi |x|^2 t}\,\mathrm d t
$$
where $B_s(x) = \mathcal F((1+|x|^2)^{-s/2})$ and $\omega_s = \frac{2\,\pi^{s/2}}{\Gamma(s/2)}$. To prove it, you can proceed as I did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220006/computing-the-fourier-transform-of-exponential-decay-in-mathbbr2/4220125#4220125) in the case of $s = d+1$.

At $x=0$, it is convergent if $s>d$, and then $B_s(0) = \frac{\omega_s}{2} \int_0^\infty t^{\frac{d-s}{2}-1}\, e^{-\pi/t}\,\mathrm d t = \frac{\omega_s}{\omega_{s-d}}$.

If $s<d$, it behaves in the same way as $\mathcal F(|x|^{-s}) = \frac{\omega_s}{\omega_{d-s}\,|x|^{d-s}}$.