# Show that $\frac 1{4\pi |x|} e^{-c|x|}$ is a fundamental solution for $-\Delta+c^2$ on $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation, fundamental-solution

> [Introduction to Partial Differential Equations - Gerald B. Folland, chapter 2, section C, question 6]
>
> Show that
> $$\frac 1{4\pi |r|} e^{-c|r|}$$
> is a fundamental solution for
> $$-\Delta+c^2\qquad (c\in \mathbb C)$$
> on $\mathbb R^3$.

I have been able to show that it is indeed a solution, i.e.,
$$\Delta F = c^2F$$
But, I can't figure out how to show that it is a fundamental solution. Please help me in that.

Also, the way I proved that it is a solution, it took me pages of hardwork - will it be possible to simplify the calculations somehow?

Note that I know what a [Fundamental Solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution) is. I just don't see any way to complete the required calculation in finite amount of time :)

---

Note that here $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Comment: What needs to be established in order for this to be a Fundamental solution?

Comment: See [Fundamental solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution).

Comment: "I have been able to show that it is indeed a solution."

A solution to what?

Comment: @Didier please check the edits

Comment: Fundamental solution doesn't mean "it's a solution of the homogeneous equation $(-\Delta+c^2)F=0$  that's also fundamental" for some meaning of the word fundamental. It means instead "it's a solution of the inhomogeneous impulse equation $(-\Delta +c^2)F=\delta$. If you have showed that it is a solution to this equation, then you're done.

Comment: You can just use the Fourier transform as in here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220006/computing-the-fourier-transform-of-exponential-decay-in-mathbbr2/4220125#4220125 (replacing $d+1$ by $2$ in the proof). Or use the result and compute the convolution of exponentials ...